# How to records the number of hours each month an employee worked in an ER diagram between two entities?

Tags: database, entity-relationship, erd, database-management

So we have two entities, **employee**, and **group**

1. An employee is uniquely identified by an *id* and has a *name*
2. A group is uniquely identified by *name* and has a *department*
3. An employee may work in multiple groups, and each group contains many
   employees
4. You should also record the number of hours an employee worked each
   month for a particular group. **Note that the employees do not work
   the same number of hours each month**.

[image]

I was able to make an ER diagram for 1 to 3, but I am having trouble with the number 4. How can I represent the fourth requirement in my ER diagram?

Answer (score 1):

Note that **more than 2** entities can be part of a **relationship**. In your problem the solution would be something like this:

[image: 3-way-relationship]

You should also **consider** setting the participation of each entity to the relationship via the lines (zero to one, one to many and so on).